# Correct way to add loading and error message using useContext and react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a context.js file which effectively makes an ajax call and stores the data in an array, so it can be shared across components. Currently I have added some 'loading ...' text in-between the ajax request loading using axios. I am sure there is a better way to do it whether the loading/error variable is passed from the context, but I am unsure, also this approach would not fit in handling error messages. So far my components are:

**Context.js**

```
import {createContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const DataContext = createContext ();

export const DataProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState ([]);
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  useEffect (
    () => {
      let mounted = true;
      const loadData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios (url);
          if (mounted) {
          setItem (response.data);
          console.log('data mounted')
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log (err);
        }
      };
      loadData ();
      return () => {
        mounted = false;
        console.log ('cleaned');
      };
    },
    [url]
  );

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{item}}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**component.js**

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import {DataContext} from '../../context/DataContext';

const Component1 = () => {
    const {item} = useContext(DataContext);

    const mappedElement = item.map(inner => {
        return (
            <ul key={inner.id}>{inner.title}</ul>
        )
    })

    const list = (element) => {
        if (element.length === 0 || null) {
            return <p>Loading ...</p>
        } else {
            return mappedElement;
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
        {list(item)}
        </>
    ) 
}

export default Component1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is to extend your context data with information about loading process and error, like:

**Context.js**

```
  const [contextState, setContextState] = useState({isLoading: true, items: [], error: null});
  // update state according to logic ...
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{contextState.items}} isLoading={{contextState.isLoading}} error={{contextState.error}}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
```

**Component.js**

```
const Component = () => {
    const {error, isLoading, items} = useContext(DataContext);

    if (error) {
       return <ErrorComponent .../>
    }
    
    if (isLoading) {
       return <LoadingSpinner />
    }
    
    return <ListComponent items={{items}}/>
}
```